# How to delete files from a .tar archive older than a certain date

Tags: bash, shell, gzip, tar

I have a .tar file that is updated with new files daily. However, after a file is older than 60 days it is worthless and no longer needs to be in the archive. How would I delete files from a .tar archive older than 60 days?

I know there is a `--delete` option, but I'm not sure how I would search the archive for files that meet that criteria.

Comment: Honestly, it'd probably be easier to write this in Python with the standard-library [`tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html).

Comment: BTW, one important thing to note here is that tar isn't a storage format designed for random access (like zip is, for example). It was designed for tape drives, so everything was streaming; there's no index that can be updated for fast random access, and if your tar files are compressed, `tar --delete` doesn't even _pretend_ to support in-place edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use a language that builds in the facilities you need. Python, for example, has a `tarfile` module, and the below shows how you can embed a Python script for the purpose inside a larger script written in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tarfilter_script=$(cat <<'EOF'
import sys
import tarfile
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

delete_older_than = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=60)).timestamp()

with tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdin.buffer) as tar_in, \
     tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdout.buffer, mode="w") as tar_out:
    for tarinfo in tar_in:
        if tarinfo.mtime >= delete_older_than:
            tar_out.addfile(tarinfo)
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(f"Skipping file: {tarinfo}\n")
EOF
)

python3 -c "$tarfilter_script" <in.tar >out.tar
```